# jquery dataTables plugin: dynamically modify ajaxSource

Tags: jquery, datatables

on my page i have [dataTable](http://datatables.net/), which was initialized with, for example, sAjaxSource url like "/api/reports". when we're doing sorting, filtering it appends to url additional query-keys. I want do add keys "date_from" and "date_to" to sAjaxSource url (date intervals could be changed after table initialization).
is there any entry-point function, before table reload, so i can do there smth like:

```
var oSettings = rtbl.fnSettings();
oSettings.sAjaxSource = "/api/reports/?type=sites&date_from=" + $("#date_from").text() + "&date_to=" + $("#date_to").text();
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this to use the [fnServerParams](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks) function of datatables, when creating the table:

```
fnServerParams: function(aoData) {
              aoData.push({ name: "type", value: 'sites' });
              aoData.push({ name: "date_from", value: $("#date_from").text() });
              aoData.push({ name: "date_to", value: $("#date_to").text() });
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

so, i've solved it, by next, quite dummy, way:

```
function set_sAjaxSource(){
                var oSettings = rtbl.fnSettings();
                oSettings.sAjaxSource = "/api/reports/?type=sites&date_from=" + $("#date_from").val() + "&date_to=" + $("#date_to").val();
            }

            $('.sorting').bind('click', set_sAjaxSource)
            $('.sorting_asc').bind('click', set_sAjaxSource)
            $('.sorting_desc').bind('click', set_sAjaxSource)
            $('.sorting_desc').bind('click', set_sAjaxSource)
            $('.paginate_button').bind('click', set_sAjaxSource)
            $('.sorting_active').bind('click', set_sAjaxSource)
```